# Always deleting last row of table in MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have 2 forms in same razor view.

1.First form is used to populate 2 dropdownlist's in ajax add model popup.
2.Second form is used to populate the added values from first form in the same view.

I can't able to use @model IEnumerable so i am getting it as viewbag collection and populating datatable.

Final task is need to add delete button in each button in datatable and remove the row accordingly.

But i can't able to get the id of each row of button click on http post.

Please look into the complete code. I am struck up for past 2 days. Please help me soon...

Controller:

```
 public class MappingK360Controller : Controller
{
    private readonly K360ECommerceSContext _context;
    public MappingK360Controller(K360ECommerceSContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
      
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        GetMappedDataDt();
        Get3PProductCatalogJson();
        GetK360ProductCatalogDB();
        return View();
    }
    public void GetMappedDataDt()
    {
        var resultMappedData = _context.K360Masters.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM K360_Master WHERE ClientCatalog is NOT NULL").ToList();
        ViewBag.K360MappedData = resultMappedData;
    }
    public void Get3PProductCatalogJson()
    {
        string strAPIUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wedeploy-examples/supermarket-web-example/master/products.json";
        string jsonUrlProducts;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            jsonUrlProducts = client.DownloadString(strAPIUrl);
        }
        Dictionary<string, object> Jsondictresults = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var objResponseB = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(jsonUrlProducts);
        foreach (Dictionary<string, object> DictMainKV in objResponseB)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in DictMainKV)
            {
                Jsondictresults.Add(item.Key, item.Key);
            }
            break;
        }
        ViewBag.TPartyJsonCtgls = Jsondictresults.Keys;
        ViewData["JsonCatalogs"] = Jsondictresults;
    }
    public void GetK360ProductCatalogDB()
    {
        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfosSM = typeof(CatalogProduct).GetProperties();
        Dictionary<string, object> K360dictresults = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfoDB in propertyInfosSM)
        {
            K360dictresults.Add(propertyInfoDB.Name, propertyInfoDB.Name);
        }
        ViewBag.K360dbCtgls = K360dictresults.Keys;
        ViewData["K360Catalogs"] = K360dictresults;
    }
   
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Index(K360Master K360LevelAMap)
    {
        try
        {
            List<K360Master> K360MasterList = _context.K360Masters.Where
              (x => x.ClientCatalog == K360LevelAMap.ClientCatalog).ToList();
            if (K360MasterList.Count > 0)
            {
                GetMappedDataDt();
                Get3PProductCatalogJson();
                GetK360ProductCatalogDB();
                ViewBag.Message = "Selected Catalog is already Mapped!";
            }
            else
            {
                _context.K360Masters.Add(K360LevelAMap);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                int id = K360LevelAMap.Id;
                ViewBag.Message = "Inserted Mapped ID: " + id;
                GetMappedDataDt();
                Get3PProductCatalogJson();
                GetK360ProductCatalogDB();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        return View(K360LevelAMap);
    }



 

    [HttpPost("DeleteK360Data")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult DeleteK360Data()
    {
        int intDeleteid = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["KDataId"]);
        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"DELETE FROM K360_Master WHERE ID = {intDeleteid}");
        GetMappedDataDt();
        Get3PProductCatalogJson();
        GetK360ProductCatalogDB();
        return View("Index");
    }
   

}}
```

View: `@model SimplCommerce.WebHost.Models.K360Master @using SimplCommerce.WebHost.Models;`

```
 <table id="Table1" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="50%" valign="top">
                    <fieldset class="border p-2">
                        <legend class="w-auto"><span style="color:red">Catalog Mapping:</span></legend>

                        <table id="Table2" width="100%" valign="top">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="25%" valign="top">
                                    <ol>
                                        @foreach (var smctgls in ViewBag.TPartyJsonCtgls)
                                        {
                                            <li>@smctgls</li>
                                        }
                                    </ol>
                                </td>
                                <td width="50%" valign="top" height="20px">

                                    <ol>
                                        @foreach (var dbctgls in ViewBag.K360dbCtgls)
                                        {
                                            <li>
                                                @dbctgls
                                            </li>
                                        }
                                    </ol>

                                </td>
                                <td width="25%" valign="top">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Catalog Mapping</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>

                                    <form method="post" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="MappingK360">
                                        <div id="exampleModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                        <h5 class="modal-title">K360 Mapping Form</h5>
                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label>Client Catalog:</label>
                                                            @{var Jsonlist = new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["JsonCatalogs"], "Value", "Key");}
                                                            <select asp-items="Jsonlist" asp-for="ClientCatalog" class="form-control"></select>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label>K360 Catalog:</label>
                                                            @{var K360list = new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["K360Catalogs"], "Value", "Key");}
                                                            <select asp-items="K360list" asp-for="K360catalog" class="form-control"></select>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>

                                    @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
                                    {
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            window.onload = function () {
                                                alert("@ViewBag.Message");
                                            };
                                        </script>
                                    }

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </fieldset>
                </td>
                <td width="50%" valign="top">
                    <fieldset class="border p-2">
                        <legend class="w-auto"><span style="color:red">Mapped Data:</span></legend>

                        @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteK360Data", "MappingK360", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@
                            <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Client Catalog</th>
                                        <th>K360 Catalog</th>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                    <tr>

                                        @foreach (K360Master Mappeddata in ViewBag.K360MappedData)
                                        {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>@Mappeddata.Id</td>
                                            <td>@Mappeddata.ClientCatalog</td>
                                            <td>@Mappeddata.K360catalog</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div>
                                                    @{TempData["KDataId"] = @Mappeddata.Id;}
                                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" />

                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    }

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            }

                   
                    </fieldset>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>


public class K360Master
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClientCatalog { get; set; }
    public string K360catalog { get; set; }
```

Comment: If I had to guess I would bet one of the things is using 0 based indexing and the other is using 1 based indexing which is always leaving the last row missing.

Comment: It's just that TempData["KDataId"] set current ID and gets overwritten every loop until TempData["KDataId"] set last ID before loop ends. So the TempData["KDataId"] is always last ID.

Comment: @asherguru, ya i observe that. so in foreach loop tempdata is not worth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View. Remove your Html.BeginForm.

```
<td>
   <a onclick='Delete(@Mappeddata.Id)'>Delete</a>
</td>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
   function Delete(id) {
       $.post('@Url.Action("DeleteK360Data")', { id: id }).done(function () {
          // your code when done
       });
   }
</script>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DeleteK360Data(id) {
    // delete your data
}
```

### EDITED

Download sample https://gofile.io/d/b4ZEs6.

### UPDATED

```
<form method="post">
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
             <th></th>
             <th>..</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         @{
              foreach (var item in Model)
              {
                 <tr>
                    <td><button asp-action="DeleteK360Data" asp-route-Id="@item.Id">Delete</button></td>
                    <td>..</td>
                 </tr>
              }
          }
      </tbody>
   </table>
</form>
```

Comment: sorry i am not good in javascript function

Comment: forgot to add [HttpPost]. Please see 'Controller' post.

Comment: If you don't have jquery.js, please use it.

Comment: @ asherguru,DeleteK360Data(id) >> id showing error

Comment: this code is common and working fine. other answer is also common and working too. you need to debug why it shows error. Like breakpoint in javascript in F12 developer console in chrome, etc.

Comment: you can download sample i made for you - https://gofile.io/d/b4ZEs6  you go check. i added 2 buttons using <form> and jquery.

Comment: ,thanks a lot.Will look into it and get back to you soon

Comment: btw, if use jquery, don't need to use <form>. <form> is for button or input type=submit only.

Comment: ,When i replace model Models.K360Master to model List<K360Master>

Comment: If look into my code, i have Select html helper in ajax model popup and it shows error

Comment: List<k360Master> does not definition for ClientCatalog and no accessbile method

Comment: <select asp-items="Jsonlist" asp-for="ClientCatalog" class="form-control"></select>.. asp-for="ClientCatalog" shows error

Comment: no need to copy all K360Master etc. you just use <form> + button or jquery button into your existing project. that's all.

Comment: ya tried first jquery  $.post('@Url.Action("DeleteAjax")', { id: id }) not firing

Comment: then you use <form> + button one. it should work.

Comment: Delete form working like a gem!. Thanks a lot from my bottom of heart for your kind effort

Comment: Glad to hear. I updated post for working code (in your case). Please mark this as solved. Thanks.

Comment: i am new to stack overflow. Don't know to mark as solved. Now i did that. Sorry for delay.

Comment: ,again post one more question in the same task. If possible please look it ino it

Comment: now one immediate task for me. i have created new question.please look into your free time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66227012/dynamic-controls-creation-based-on-json-url-in-dotnet-core-mvc

Answer (score 0):

in the foreach() loop you are overriding the value for TempData['KDataId'] at each itaration.
So, it will always be the id of the last K360Master object.

Instead you should send the desired id as a parameter, refactoring your controller method :

```
public IActionResult DeleteK360Data(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

And in your view :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteK360Data", new { id = @Mappeddata.Id})
```

(adapt it to generate the desired html tag such as button or whatever you want).

And don't forget to use [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute on your controller's methods (not related to your question, but good practice).

Comment: public IActionResult DeleteK360Data(int id) .Id value is 0 always so that i try to sent through tempdata

Comment: You really have to do it like that. You should determine why the 'id' value is always 0 ; can you share your code of this version (controller) ? Maybe the route or some attribute is missing.

Comment: You did not modified the code as I suggested

Comment: i have modified as you suggest but id value is o so i revert back it

Comment: Ok but you are running a king of X-Y problem
Your goal now is to determine why id is 0, don't revert the code, it's the right way to to
Maybe try to modify he HttpPost attribute to include the id parameter.